# Order of duplicates is reversed in iOS app

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, ios-app, dupehammer

Users with gold tag badges can close a question as a duplicate of multiple other questions. When they do so they can also set the order that the duplicate displays in. I recently closed [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222341/snape-muttering-his-little-counter-curse) and very deliberately arranged the list order:

[image: Screenshot of closed question]

However when I open the question in the iOS app, the duplicate order is reversed:

[image: Screenshot of question in iOS app]

Comment: Obligatory comment about no one working on the app...

Comment: Already reported by other Alex, and even had the honor of being rejected. (Since 99.999% of the bugs/requests are just ignored.)